# Is it possible to do XQuery through linq?

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-xml, xquery

I have an XML field which has about 5MB of data every record, but sometimes, I only need to read a small part of the XML field. As you can imagine, if I read the whole XML field and then using Linq-to-XML to parse the XML file and gather the value, it would be too slow and expensive. So I want know, is it possible to get a value directly using Linq instead of read the whole XML field?

My DB is SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

With the current information provided I think the best solution is to use an XML index in SQL Server.

There are four types of XML indexes:

1. Primary
2. Secondary for PATH
3. Secondary for PROPERTY
4. Secondary for VALUE

In your case it appears you know the path to the data you want, naturally a secondary PATH index seems to be the best fit.

**Follow these steps to create this index:**

Create primary index

```
create primary xml index XIX_XmlColumnName on XmlTable(XmlColumnName)
go
```

This will create the "base" index for your xml column, basically this means that the xml will be shredded to a hidden table and stored with values where every element is turned into one row.

Create secondary path index

```
create xml index XIX_XmlColumnName_Path on XmlTable(XmlColumnName)
using xml index XIX_XmlColumnName for path
go
```

This will create a secondary index using the path-column in the primary index (which we now know is a table).

Finally, run a (sql) query such as this in a procedure and call that from your application:

```
select XmlColumnName.query('/path/to/element')
from XmlTable
```

*Granted, this is not a linq-query/solution, but imo it's always best to use a tool that fits, and not try to force it.*

For more in-depth information about xml indexes, see [this msdn-article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345121%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! But even use the XmlReader, I think I will still need to read the entire XML field from the database (this will slow down my application, I think), then use the XmlReader to pick the value that I want.